# How to split an iterator based on a condition on prev and curr elements?

Tags: scala

I want to split a list of elements into a list of lists such that neighboring elements in the inner list satisfy a given condition.

A simple condition would be neighboring elements are equal. Then if the input is `List(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)` output is `List(List(1,1,1),List(2,2),List(3,3,3))`.

Another condition could be current element should be greater than prev element. Then if the input is `List(1,2,3,1,4,6,5,7,8)`, the output is `List(List(1,2,3), List(1,4,6), List(5,7,8))`. It would also be wonderful if the method can act on `Iterator`. The typedef of the method is

```
def method[A](lst:List[A], cond:(A,A)=>Boolean):List[List[A]]
def method[A](lst:Iterator[A], cond:(A,A)=>Boolean):Iterator[Iterator[A]]
```

Comment: I don't think your first example makes much sense. What do you mean by "neighboring elements are equal" ? The neighbors of `2` are not equal anywhere in the list. For a `List(..., prev, curr, next)`, should `prev == next` or should `prev == curr`? Or `curr == next`?

Comment: http://qnalist.com/questions/5440180/groupingiterator for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sliding` together with `span` in a recursive function for the desired effect.  This quick and dirty version is less efficient, but terser than some of the alternative:

```
def method[A](lst: TraversableOnce[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
    val iterable = lst.toIterable
    iterable.headOption.toList.flatMap { head => 
        val (next, rest) = iterable.sliding(2).filter(_.size == 2).span(x => cond(x.head, x.last))
        (head :: next.toList.map(_.last)) :: method(rest.map(_.last), cond)
    }
}
```

If you want to lazily execute the code, you can return an `Iterator[List[A]]` instead of `List[List[A]]`:

```
def method[A](lst: TraversableOnce[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Iterator[List[A]] = {
    val iterable = lst.toIterable
    iterable.headOption.toIterator.flatMap { head => 
        val (next, rest) = iterable.sliding(2).filter(_.size == 2).span(x => cond(x.head, x.last))
        Iterator(head :: next.toList.map(_.last)) ++ method(rest.map(_.last), cond)
    }
}
```

And you can verify that this is lazy:

```
val x = (Iterator.range(0, 10) ++ Iterator.range(3, 5) ++ Iterator.range(1, 3)).map(x => { println(x); x })
val iter = method(x, (x: Int, y: Int) => x < y) //Only prints 0-9, and then 3!
iter.take(2).toList //Prints more
iter.toList //Prints the rest
```

You can make it even lazier by returning an `Iterator[Iterator[A]]`:

```
def method[A](lst: TraversableOnce[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Iterator[Iterator[A]] = {
    val iterable = lst.toIterable
    iterable.headOption.toIterator.flatMap { head => 
        val (next, rest) = iterable.sliding(2).filter(_.size == 2).span(x => cond(x.head, x.last))
        Iterator(Iterator(head) ++ next.toIterator.map(_.last)) ++ method(rest.map(_.last), cond)
    }
}
```

As a relatively unrelated side note, when you have generic parameters of this form, you're better off using 2 parameter lists:

```
def method[A](lst: TraversableOnce[A])(cond: (A, A) => Boolean)
```

When you have 2 parameter lists like this, the type inference can be a little bit smarter:

```
//No need to specify parameter types on the anonymous function now!
method(List(1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8, 1))((x, y) => x < y).toList
//You can now even use underscore anonymous function notation!
method(List(1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8))(_ < _)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, though. `method(List(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8),{(a:Int,b:Int) => a < b} )` gives `List(List(1, 2, 3), List(), List(1, 4, 6), List(5, 7 , 8))` (note the unwanted empty list - there's one for the == case too). And it doesn't work on Iterators.

Comment: Running the code you wrote for me returns `List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 4, 6), List(5, 7, 8))`, as desired -- are you sure about running this exact code?  As for `Iterators`, this solution relies on `zip` with itself, so it doesn't work well with `Iterators`.  Of course, you could call `toList` if that is an option.

Comment: @Paul I've updated the answer so it works with `Iterators` now.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure (I cut and pasted the code and result from a Scala IDE 4.0 worksheet). Your latest modified version works, though

Comment: I see that we use list.last inside the method. If  I have a large iterator, wouldn't this be a problem. Ideally  I would return a Iterator[Iterator[A]]. But I   like this solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: We call `last` on the result of `sliding(2)`, which is will only have length 2.  It would be equivalent to get the second element.  But this solution isn't the most efficient!

Comment: @Arun I've added an update that makes the method return an `Iterator`, so it behaves lazily.  This is now probably efficient enough for most cases due to the laziness!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something close (I believe) to what you are asking for.  The only issue with this is that it always produces a List of Lists for the result as opposed to being based on the input type:

```
  val iter = Iterator(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
  val list = List(4,5,5,5,5,6,6)

  def same(a:Int,b:Int) = a == b
  def gt(a:Int, b:Int) = b > a

  println(groupByPred(iter, same))
  println(groupByPred(list, gt))

  def groupByPred[L <: TraversableOnce[T], T](trav:L, cond:(T,T) => Boolean):List[List[T]] = {
    val (ret, inner) = 
      trav.foldLeft((List.empty[List[T]], List.empty[T])){
        case ((acc, list), el) if list.isEmpty || cond(list.head, el) => (acc,el :: list)
        case ((acc, list), el)  => (list.reverse :: acc,el :: List.empty)
      }
    (inner.reverse :: ret).reverse
  }
```

If you run that code, the output should be the following:

```
List(List(1, 1), List(2, 2, 2), List(3, 3, 3))
List(List(4, 5), List(5), List(5), List(5, 6), List(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Puts the head of the list as the first element of the first element of the List of Lists. Then adds things to that first List if the condition holds. If it doesn't, starts a new List with the current entry as the first element.

Both the inner list and the outer are constructed in the wrong order. So reverse each element of the outer List (with map) and then reverse the outer list.

```
  val xs = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
  val ys = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8)

  def method[A](lst: List[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
    lst.tail.foldLeft(List(List(lst.head))) { (acc, e) =>
      if (cond(acc.head.head, e))
        (e :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
      else List(e) :: acc
    }.map(_.reverse).reverse
  }

method(xs, { (a: Int, b: Int) => a == b })
//> res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1), List(2, 2), List(3, 3, 3, 3))
method(ys, { (a: Int, b: Int) => a < b })
//> res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 4, 6), List(5, 7, 8))
```

Iterator overload

```
def method[A](iter:Iterator[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
 val h = iter.next
   iter.foldLeft(List(List(h))) { (acc, e) =>
     if (cond(acc.head.head, e))
       (e :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
     else List(e) :: acc
   }.map(_.reverse).reverse
 }

method(xs.toIterator, { (a: Int, b: Int) => a == b })
//> res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1), List(2, 2), List(3, 3, 3, 3))
method(ys.toIterator, { (a: Int, b: Int) => a < b })
//> res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 4, 6), List(5, 7, 8))
```

More generic version (hat-tip to @cmbaxter for some ideas here) that works with Lists, Iterators and anything that can be traversed once:

```
def method[A, T <: TraversableOnce[A]](trav: T, cond: (A, A) => Boolean)
: List[List[A]] = {
    trav.foldLeft(List(List.empty[A])) { (acc, e) =>
      if (acc.head.isEmpty || !cond(acc.head.head, e)) List(e) :: acc
      else (e :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
    }.map(_.reverse).reverse
  }
```